# Magento 2 admin order grid model filters based on conditions

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, grid, model, resource-model

I have overridden Magento's default order grid controller. I'm trying to apply different filters based on the custom cookie I set.

My di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection"   type="Salesfilter\Grid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection" />
</config>
```

This override is working fine!

My class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Salesfilter\Grid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

/**
 * Order grid collection
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param Logger $logger
     * @param FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy
     * @param EventManager $eventManager
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param string $resourceModel
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'sales_order_grid',
        $resourceModel = \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::class
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
       $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
       $param = $request->getParam('allorder');
       parent::_initSelect();
       if(isset($_COOKIE['Allorders_cookie'])) {
       $tableDescription = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
       foreach ($tableDescription as $columnInfo) {
           $this->addFilterToMap($columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME'], 'main_table.' . $columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME']);
           $this->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status'); 
           $this->addFieldToFilter('status',['processing']);  
 
       }

        }else{
       $allorders = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
       foreach ($allorders as $allorder) {
           $this->addFilterToMap($allorder['COLUMN_NAME'], 'main_table.' . $allorder['COLUMN_NAME']);
           $this->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status');  
           $this->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('processing','pending')));

       }

        }
       return $this;

    }
}
```

The cookie check condition is working but the collection didn't re-initiate when another condition is satisfied. It seems like the addFieldToFilter is stuck and again not applying for the whole collection.
If the page is loaded with cookie first then the condition is satisfied and loaded. Again if the cookie is unset the other else is not working, it is not re-initiating the collection.

Comment: Have you check that your file called every time or not?

Comment: yes it is called everytime even cookie present or not present

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in you class you need to extend the overridden class name.

**Wrong**

`class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult`

**Correct**

`class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection`

Comment: after changing to extends class my problem got resolved